# Как отрефакторить данный код, чтобы не было повторений и много строк?

Tags: javascript

```
this.a = obj.a;
this.b = obj.b;
this.c = obj.c;
this.d = obj.d;
this.e = obj.e;
```

Comment: В целом можно цикл, но для понятности лучше оставить так, имхо

Comment: А для чего вам каждое свойство так переписывать? почему не сделать this.data = obj ? а дальше обращаться this.data.a

Comment: Подобное не стоит рефакторить (имхо). В вашем случае это не повторения, это инициализация чего-то. И что значит "много строк кода"? 5 строк это не много, если вот 50 подобных инициализаций - стоит задуматься правильно ли вы всё делаете или может стоит разделить обязанности?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать деструктуризацию для присвоения множественных значений за один раз:

```js
obj = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd',
  e: 'e'
}

let { a, b, c, d, e } = obj

console.log(a, b, c, d, e)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
};

function create(source) {
  Object.assign(this, source);
}

const d = new create(obj);
console.log(d);
```

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5
};

function create(source) {
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].forEach(i => this[i] = source[i]);
}

const d = new create(obj);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]